# I've forgotten my password

Tags: password

Its been some time since I've turned on my Dell XG-600 lap-top. When I finally turned it on, I discovered that for the life of me I cannot remember the password, let alone the pass phrase, which is a mystery to me.Can anybody be of assistance in helping me resolve this small, but annoying problem?

Comment: Just follow instructions provided here: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

When booting you can select Recovery Mode in GRUB, this will give you a root shell.

From there you can simply:

```
passwd [username]
```

and change the password for your user.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

In the grub menu, choose for the “recovery mode” option.

**Step 2:**

Here you need to choose “Root Drop into root shell prompt“.

**Step 3:**

Use the following command to reset the password for the selected “username“:

```
passwd username
```

It prompts for new password. Enter the new password twice:

```
Enter new UNIX password:

Retype new UNIX password:
```

Those were quick steps. You can follw the detailed tutorial with screenshots here: http://itsfoss.com/how-to-hack-ubuntu-password/